# Recursion difficulty

Tags: c, recursion

I'm having some trouble understanding a part of this code. The part I'm talking about is in the function term_min, where the function is called within its own body, and used as a parameter for function minim (return minim(array[arraySize], term_min(arraySize - 1)); ).
Could someone explain me what that bit actually does? Here's the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* The program computes the minimum of a array of integer numbers*/

#define NMAX 100
#define MAXIMUM INT_MAX
int array[NMAX];

int minim(int x, int y)
{
 if (x <= y) return x;
 else return y;
}

int term_min(int arraySize)
{
 if (arraySize >= 0) return minim(array[arraySize], term_min(arraySize - 1)); //here's where I have trouble understanding 
 else return MAXIMUM;
}

int main(void)
{
 int i, n;
 printf("\nInput the number of the elements of the array n=");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("\nInput the values of the elements\n");

 for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
    printf("array[%d]=", i);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

 printf("\nInput array is:\n");

 for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
    printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    if ((i+1) % 10 == 0) printf("\n");
    }

 printf("\nThe minimum is %d\n", term_min(n-1));
 printf("\nPress a key!");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your doubt or question? working of recursive functions?

Comment: Were you able to compile? I can't find the definition of INT_MAX.

Comment: Yes I am able to compile&run, INT_MAX is defined in limits.h as the maximal value which can be stored in an int variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda a goofy way to compute the minimum of the array, but essentially what it is doing is counting out all of the numbers, unless you call it with 0, where it returns the greatest possible number an int can be for your OS.

It's essentially doing this, for an array of 10:

```
minim( array[9], minim( array[8], minim( array[7], minim( array[6], minim( array[5], minim( array[4], minim( array[3], minim( array[2], minim( array[1], minim( array[0], INT_MAX)))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you could use `strace`. If you're using an IDE you could use your debugger. Or, you could add some printf(s) to your  `term_min` call. The function `minim` returns the smaller of two values (x or y). Finally, `main(void)` should be `main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Answer (score 0):

`term_min` is pretty straight-forward: unless `arraySize` is negative, it calls `minim` with the last element of the array (using the misleadingly-named `arraySize`) and the minimum of the preceding elements of that array.  It just so happens that the way it computes the minimum of that subset of the array is to use another instance of that very function.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it this way:

For function `int term_min(int arraySize)` , so long the `arraySize is >= 0`, keep on running the recursion, till goal is met. (Your goal is to get the minimum array value)

`if (arraySize >= 0) return minim(array[arraySize], term_min(arraySize - 1));` means:

- So long arraySize >=0, continue running the recursion

`return minim(array[arraySize], term_min(arraySize - 1));` means:

- Get the **last** and **second last** array element and comprare which is smaller by calling `minim()` and return the value of the smaller element.
- Everytime you do this, arraySize is reduced. This process is continued till arraySize reaches -1 (according to your codes)
- And when that happens, you find the smallest array value (if there exist one).